# Android Studio won't print using variable "Int"

Tags: java, android-studio, variables

Sorry if I haven't phrased that question right but here's my problem:
As per the screenshot, I was expecting "3" and "120" in the console when I ran the code but instead got "myInt" "myByte". How do I fix this ?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYXYn.png)

Comment: You're not printing the variables, you're printing literal strings.  Remove the quotes.

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/training/index.html](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

Comment: Please read about variables and strings https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Comment: please post the code and the output as text, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(myInt);
```

Note that `myInt` does not come with `""` here! What you are doing is actually printing the String "myInt". But if you want to print the value of the variable myInt, just put `myInt` without `""`.

Answer (score 0):

`"myInt"` is a `String` so it prints it literally

`myInt` is the variable, and it allows to transport its value

So :

- `System.out.println("myInt") - > //   myInt`
- `System.out.println(myInt) - >   //   3`

---

You can use both :

`System.out.println("The value of myInt is " + myInt) - > //  The value of myInt is 3`

Answer (score 0):

You are surrounding the variable names with double quotes. Remove them and you'll be good to go.

```
public class Variables{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int myInt = 3;
    byte myByte =120;
    System.out.println(myiInt);
    System.out.println(myiByte);
  }
}
```